# Pandas create multiple aggregations

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to see how hard or easy this is to do with Pandas.

Let's say one has a two columns with data such as:

```
Cat1  Cat2
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        1
B        2
C        1
C        2
C        3
D        4
```

As you see `A` and `C` have three common elements `1, 2, 3`. `B` however has only two elements 1 and 2. `D` has only one element: 4.

How would one programmatically get to this same result. The idea will be to have each group returned somehow. So one will be `[A, C]` and `[1, 2, 3]`, then `[B]` and `[1, 2]` and `[D]` with `[4]`.

I know a program can be written to do this so I am trying to figure out if there is something on Pandas to do it without having to build stuff from scratch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby` twice to achieve this.

```
df = df.groupby('Cat1')['Cat2'].apply(lambda x: tuple(set(x))).reset_index()
df = df.groupby('Cat2')['Cat1'].apply(lambda x: tuple(set(x))).reset_index()
```

I'm using `tuple` because pandas needs elements to be hashable in order to do a `groupby`.  The code above doesn't distinguish between `(1, 2, 3)` and `(1, 1, 2, 3)`.  If you want to make this distinction, replace `set` with `sorted`.

The resulting output:

```
        Cat2    Cat1
0     (1, 2)    (B,)
1  (1, 2, 3)  (A, C)
2       (4,)    (D,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also:

```
df = df.set_index('Cat1', append=True).unstack().loc[:, 'Cat2']
df = pd.Series({col: tuple(values.dropna()) for col, values in df.items()})
df = df.groupby(df.values).apply(lambda x: list(x.index))
```

to get

```
                   Cat1
(1.0, 2.0)          [B]
(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)  [A, C]
(4.0,)              [D]
```